# How to get typescript http.get observable to wait for parameter to be returned inline?

Tags: typescript, promise, observable, httprequest, angular2-observables

Ok so I am trying to get the http.get call I am making to wait for one of the parameters (getUserToken) to be returned before calling into the http.get function.  I don't want to chain them together here because my calling function getSomeData returns an observable that is then called by lots of other functions.

getSomeData is the one needing getUserToken to be returned but getUserToken is always null because I am not doing the promise thing correctly.  I am sorry I just am not seeing the solution here.

this function kicks off the call, there are lots of functions that make this call, I don't want to have to change anything here.

```
displayData(){
 let mySubscription = this.getSomeData();
    mySubscription.subscribe(retJson => {
      if (retJson != null && retJson !== undefined){
        console.log(retJson);
      }
    });
}
```

This is the call that returns the http.get the problem is here in getUserToken.  I need the http.get to wait for the getUserToken().

```
getSomeData(){
     let temporary = this.http.get(serviceUrl, getUserToken() ).map((response: Response) => {
       return response;
  });
return temporary;
}
```

The problem is that getUserToken makes its own call to the server, is there a way to wrap this in an observable or promise that can be called and resolved inline of the http.get inside the getSomeData call?

```
getUserToken(){
     this.authenticationService.getToken()
            .subscribe(responseData => {
              if (responseData){
                let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + responseData.token });
                return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
              }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `switchMap`.

```
@Injectable()
class SomeClass {
   // Constructor omitted

   public displayData():void {
      const subscription:Subscription = this.getSomeData()
         .filter(retJson => !!retJson) // Only if json is truthy
         .subscribe(console.log);
   }

   // Get the user token, then switch to the actual data
   private getSomeData():Observable<any /*Replace with correct data type*/ > {
      return this.getUserToken() // get the user token
         .switchMap(userToken => // This is the token -> switchMap basically subscribes to the getUserToken and returns another observable
            this.http.get(serviceUrl, // switch to another observable as soon as getUserToken gives a value
               new RequestOptions({headers: new Headers({...userToken})}) // optionally, add other headers here
            )
         );
   }

   private getUserToken():Observable<{authorization: string}> {
      return this.authenticationService.getToken()
        .filter(responseData => !!responseData) // only if responseData is truthy
        .map(responseData => ({'Authorization': `Bearer ${responseData.token}`})); // Map to the object representing the header header
   }

}
```

Or, to make the stream more obvious, you could write it like this in a single method (not recommended, only for making the stream more obvious for now):

```
const subscription:Subscription = this.authenticationService.getToken()
   .filter(responseData => !!responseData) // only if responseData is truthy
   .switchMap(userToken => // This is the token -> switchMap basically subscribes to the getUserToken and returns another observable
        this.http.get(serviceUrl, // switch to another observable as soon as getUserToken gives a value
           new RequestOptions({headers: new Headers({'Authorization': `Bearer ${responseData.token}`})}) // optionally, add other headers here
        )
    )
    .filter(retJson => !!retJson) // Only if json is truthy
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Thank you this is a solid answer, I was not aware of the switchMap. I will give this a try as soon as I can

Comment: This worked for me, thank you @pascalpuetz.  I went with a flatMap so that all the calls would be guaranteed to finish but your solution is sweet